# I need help with meaning: 「それは気の毒に...年頃だしな」

Tags: meaning, translation

それは気【き】の毒【どく】に...年頃【としごろ】だしな

How would you read this sentence?

"It is unfortunate...that age"
? It doesn't make sense to me

Edit: The context is a bit tricky because it seems to me like the old man who says it about the hormonal  teenager is a pervert

Comment: As with so much in life, **context is key**.  FWIW, your translation sounds more or less correct.  As to what that means, well, it would depend on the context.

Comment: Wild guess: father is upset that his daughter got a boyfriend.

Comment: The だしなdoesn't add something to the age part?

Comment: You need to add context so that potential answerers can understand whose age is being talked about. It's definitely not the speaker's or 'age' as in 'new age'. It is about how old somebody is.

Comment: Just give us whole sentence, not just one.

Comment: Yes, more fully Japanese sentences would be better than trying to describe the context yourself. When questioners summarize the context themselves, we have to just trust they're explaining it correctly/fully.

Answer (score 2):

年頃　basically means someone is in the transition between child and adult. Being curious about something romantic, or disobedient etc.
I don't know which English word corresponds to it, but I think its like

"It's understandable for his age".